# Can't populate the keys from firebase into FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

i want to retrieve the keys into FirebaseListAdapter not the values like this example:
[image: screenshot_1]

so i want to show "Cat" and "Dog" in the listview but i don't know how to do this cuz i searched a lot but found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default implementation of `FirebaseListAdapter` calls `getValue()` with the class you specified when constructing the adapter. By overriding `parseSnapshot` you can determine what part of each `DataSnapshot` is handed to `populateView()`. To get the key:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
        this,
        String.class,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        databaseReference
) {
     @Override
     protected String parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
         return snapshot.getKey();
     }

    @Override
    protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(model);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To display those `animals` you can use this code:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<YourClass> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<YourClass>(this, YourClass.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, yourDatabaseReference) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, YourClass yourClass, int position) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            String animal = this.getRef(position).getKey();
            textView.setText(animal);
        }
    };
```

In which `YourClass` is your model class. You can use also in stead of `YourClass` even the `String` class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying , i didn't try this but looks like it gonna work